# How to change the number in my i variable each time I run the program in Python?

Tags: python, variables, time

```
print ('What type of device?')
device=input()
if device == 'phone':
    print('What make of phone is it? iphone or android?')
    make=input()
    if make == 'iphone':
        print ('Which model is it? 5, 6 or 7?')
        model = input()
        print ('Which version?')
        version = input()
        print('How much memory, 8GB, 16GB or 32GB?')
        memory = input()
        print ('What is the problem?')
        problem = input()
        if model == '5' and version == 'S' and memory == '16GB':
            textfile=open('iphone5S16GB.txt','r')
            iphone5S16GB=textfile.readlines()
            if 'apps' in problem or 'close down' in problem or 'slow' in problem:
                print (iphone5S16GB[0])
            elif 'screen' in problem or 'display' in problem or 'monitor' in problem:
                print (iphone5S16GB[1])
            elif 'music' in problem or 'download' in problem:
                print(iphone5S16GB[2])
            else:
                i=0
                with open('casenumbers.txt','a+') as f:
                  f.write(str(i+1) + ' = casenumber \n')
                  f.close()
        elif model == '6' and version == 'S' and memory == '32GB':
            textfile=open('iphone6S32GB.txt','r')
            iphone6S32GB=textfile.readlines()
            if 'home button' in problem or 'touch id' in problem:
                print (iphone6S32GB[0])
            elif 'battery' in problem or 'charging' in problem:
                print(iphone6S32GB[1])
            elif 'hot' in problem or 'overheating' in problem:
                print(iphone6S32GB[2])
            else:
              with open('casenumbers.txt','a+') as f:
                f.write('hi this is the second test' '\r\n')
                f.close()
    else:
        print('The program only has examples for two types of iphone'
    ' but if this program were to be expanded then more solutions could be found'
    ' for many different devices')
else:
    print('The program only has examples for two types of iphone'
' but if this program were to be expanded then more solutions could be found'
' for many different devices')
```

This program has been designed to ask what type of device the user has and then ask a few questions about the device. It has then asked for the user's problem regarding their device. The program will then return a solution corresponding to the problem the user has given. If no solution is found then, it should be assigned a case number and stored in another textfile. My program works, I just need to know how to make the 'i' variable change each time I run my program. This is in the else statement. My program only needs to have examples and once I know how to do this then I can  make it happen in the next else statement. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Whenever program gets over it delete all the local variables , next time you can't check that, You must have to store the count in database somewhere so that you can check how many time it got run before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase 'i' each time the program is run you need to save 'i' in a file. For example (the file name I chose is not special):

```
i=0
try:
  with open('lastcasenumber.txt','r') as f:
    i = 1 + int(f.read())
except:
  pass
with open('casenumbers.txt','a+') as f:
  f.write(str(i+1) + ' = casenumber \n')
with open('lastcasenumber.txt','w') as f:
  f.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store 'i' in a text file. Every time you run the program, you can read from the file, increment 'i', use it and then replace it in the same file

Comment: How exactly would I do that?

Comment: After i=0, read from a file and store the result in i. Then store your case number as before. After this, increment i and store it back to the file.